# How to find out how many colors my OpenGL can represent on it's color buffer?

Tags: opengl

I am needing to know how many different colors I can use in my OpenGL application.

My situation: I am going to read back the drew pixels using glReadPixels but the color will  have an integer meaning instead of color. So I need to know how much information I can represent.

I was going to use `glGet` with GL_RED_BITS,GL_GREEN_BITS and GL_BLUE_BITS. But these are deprecated. How can I achieve this using a function that is available at least at OpenGL 3?

Comment: How about `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` with null (i.e. screen) bound? I am not sure, so posting as a comment. `pname` accepts `FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_RED_SIZE` and so on.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: That should be an answer not just a comment.

Comment: As I said, I am not sure, and I don't want to post information that I'm uncertain of. I am however digging the said function docs, and if I verify it actually works as intended, I'll post it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okey, I've found what I was looking for. My comment about [`glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter.xml) was correct, and here's some reference:

> glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv — retrieve information about
>   attachments of a bound framebuffer object

So far so good.

> If the default framebuffer is bound to target then attachment must be
>   one of GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRONT_RIGHT, GL_BACK_LEFT, or GL_BACK_RIGHT,
>   identifying a color buffer.

So yup, we can use it for screen buffer! And now the part that interests you:

`pname` can be either:

- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_GREEN_SIZE`
- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_BLUE_SIZE`
- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_ALPHA_SIZE`
- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_DEPTH_SIZE`
- `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_STENCIL_SIZE`

> `params` will contain the
>   number of bits in the corresponding red, green, blue, alpha, depth, or
>   stencil component of the specified attachment. Zero is returned if the
>   requested component is not present in attachment.

And oh, `target` can be just `GL_FRAMEBUFFER`, I think.

EDIT: You requested an example to sum it all up, so...

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
GLint ret;

glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE, &ret);

if (ret == GL_NONE)
    exit(1); // something is really bad there or FRONT_LEFT isn't your default buffer. Check it!

glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_RED_SIZE, &ret);
```

And here are possible `INVALID_ENUMS` you can get:

> - GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if target is not one of the accepted
>     tokens.
> - GL_INVALID_ENUM is generated if pname is not valid for the
>     value of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE.

Comment: Default front buffer is the left one, IIRC :) i.e. there's no "middle" buffer. Clearer? Or think about stereoscopic usage. That seems like a nice new question.

Comment: Can you give an example of usage? No matter what combinations I try I get INVALID_ENUM, =/

Comment: Please help me out in the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138085/why-is-not-glgetframebufferattachmentparameter-working thank you