# Why is not glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameter working?

Tags: opengl, glew

I am trying the following code on my device which support OpenGL3 ("OpenGL version string: 3.3.0 NVIDIA 310.19"):

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
checkGlError();
glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE, &ret);
checkGlError();

if (ret == GL_NONE)
    throw std::runtime_error("something is really bad there or FRONT_LEFT isn't your default buffer. Check it!");

glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_FRONT_LEFT, GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_RED_SIZE, &ret);
checkGlError();
```

`checkGlError` is a macro that will check for OpenGL error and tell the line which occurred an error.

I tried initialized my context using Qt and SDL. Also, I used glew to get access to the function.

On the first call to `glGetFramebufferAttachmentParameteriv` I get and INVALID_ENUM error. What can it be?

Comment: I've already listed you the possible reasons why that function could give `GL_INVALID_ENUM` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15137195/752976). Did you check them?

Comment: Anyway, that looks strange. I am still far from suspecting driver bug, but... Well. I'm puzzled.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Yes, I read it. And reread several times on the docs. Still, everything seems right to me on the given parameters.